# Batch action in Illustrator requires "OK" for every file

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to automate formatting a bunch of files with Illustrator actions. I made my action, this is what it looks like:

[image]

However, I get this annoying popup every time during the Saturate step that says "No saturable colors found" and the only option is OK, which I click, then it successfully saturates the colors. So if I'm processing a thousand files, I have to sit there and click OK for every file.

Is there any way to get rid of this popup, or to make the action click OK for me?

Comment: I can't replicate this here. Saturate performs without any confirmation. I'm wondering if it's seeing something that is 100C100M100Y100K or 0R0G0B and *that* can't be saturated perhaps. I tested that, but it doesn't *appear* to matter here.

Comment: Interesting. I checked, and there's no pure black or pure white in the artwork.

Comment: hmm. raster image maybe?

Comment: Just tried, same error. I'm just going to try to get an autoclicker to click the button for me.

Comment: Your not showing the rightmost column is it possible that you have user interaction by mistake on for that step? Or in you global options.

Comment: @joojaa not seeing a column further right, is there a way to enable it? Similarly, not sure where that setting is.

Comment: @Gjs sorry i mean left.